# Count differences in array of objects, including changes to objects?

Tags: javascript

I would like to be able to count the differences between two arrays, like down below.

The problem I'm having happens when an element is added or removed from one array. How to tell if an element added to the 1th person of the second array, is "new" as opposed to an edit of the current 1th element.

I can find all sorts of things about comparing arrays based upon the array length but nothing about the content.

The closest I've found is the [DeepDiff](https://github.com/flitbit/diff) library but I had trouble handling its return value to determine the number of differences when arrays were changed.

The real real problem is the elements of the array have no ID or unique property. :/

```
[
  {
    "aclMatchType": "IP",
    "aclName": "Test2",
    "action": {
      "deny": 0,
      "dscp": "",
      "tc": ""
    },
    "inbound": true,
    "ipv4": {
      "dstIpAddr": "",
      "dstIpAddrMask": "",
      "ipProtocol": "",
      "srcIpAddr": "192.168.1.6",
      "srcIpAddrMask": "255.255.255.0"
    },
    "mac": {
      "dstMacAddr": "",
      "dstMacAddrMask": "",
      "srcMacAddr": "",
      "srcMacAddrMask": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "aclMatchType": "IP",
    "aclName": "Test4",
    "action": {
      "deny": 0,
      "dscp": "",
      "tc": ""
    },
    "inbound": true,
    "ipv4": {
      "dstIpAddr": "",
      "dstIpAddrMask": "",
      "ipProtocol": "",
      "srcIpAddr": "192.168.1.10",
      "srcIpAddrMask": "255.255.255.0"
    },
    "mac": {
      "dstMacAddr": "",
      "dstMacAddrMask": "",
      "srcMacAddr": "",
      "srcMacAddrMask": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I see one array containing multiple objects, so you mean the difference between each object within the array?

Comment: i use the `odiff` lib, which defines new as <90% overlap. it's a question of perf balancing to update many vs replace one, which depends on the application of the diff data. `jsonpatch` libs are related, but they hardly ever batch changes, unshifting() an array of object by updating every key of every object in the array to the one before it...

Comment: Odiff is perfect! Oh my god. Life saver. Thank you @dandavis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per dandavis' suggestion, I was able to use odiff for this which covers *most* cases. Like he said, 90% diff. Good enough for my purpose.